# how to get user email address when he join a live stream without signing up

Tags: flutter, supabase, flutterflow

I am working on a livestream app in flutterflow using supabase as backend. The attendee registers for an event and we send a confirmation email to the attendee. Now when the attendee joins the live stream and starts public chat I want to fetch his username and email, but I don't want the attendee to sign up. I am using flutterflow and supabase.

I am thinking about generating an access token, will this work? If so how can I do this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.